# $n \geq 5$, prove that the $3$-cycles of $A_n$ are pairwise conjugates in $A_n$. Is this true for $n=3$ or $n=4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups

#### Question:

Let $n \geq 5$ an integer, prove that the $3$-cycles of $A_n$ are pairwise conjuguates in $A_n$. Is this true for $n=3$ or $n=4$? Explain your answer.

**I have a doubt concerning my conclusion in "-3" is it correct? Mostly because I don't see where we use the fact that $n \geq 5$ in my answer (so it seems to be correct for all $n$) But this is not the case.**
So jump directly to my part "3-" it if you do not have time.

#### My Answer:

1-
First of all let remind the definition of conjuguate permuation: Two permutations $\sigma, \sigma' \in S_n$ are conjuguate if $\exists \tau \in S_n$ s.t. $ \sigma ' = \tau \sigma \tau^{-1} $. Conjugation is a way to transform one permutation into another using a third permutation and its inverse.
*Exemple:* With $S_4$, $\sigma = (123), \sigma'=(124)$. We are looking for $\tau \in S_4$ s.t. $(234)= \tau (123) \tau^{-1}$ and $\tau = (1243)$
So here we are asked to prove that $ \forall \sigma, \sigma' \in A_n \Rightarrow \exists \tau \in A_n$ s.t. $ \sigma' = \tau \circ \sigma \circ \tau^{-1}$.

2-
Now let's chose $\sigma = (a;b;c), \sigma'=(d;e;f) ; a,b,c,d,e,f \in \left \{1;2;...;n  \right \}$ any 3-cycles in $A_n$.
Because we know that in $S_n$  it is verify $\sigma \circ ( a; b ) \circ \sigma^{-1}= (\sigma(a); \sigma (b) )$. On an other side we have $(a;b;c)=(a;b)(b;c)$.
Hence we can writte $ \tau \circ (a;b;c) \circ \tau^{-1} = \tau \circ (a;b) \circ (b;c) \circ \tau^{-1} =  \tau \circ (a;b) \circ \tau^{-1} \circ \tau \circ (b;c) \circ \tau^{-1} = (\tau(a); \tau(b)) \circ (\tau(b); \tau(c))= (\tau(a); \tau(b); \tau(c) ) $.

3-
Thus it is easy to define $ \tau(a) = d , \tau(b)=e, \tau(c)=f $, hence we have shown that for every $ \sigma, \sigma'$ of 3 cycles we can define a $\tau$ such that $ \sigma ' = \tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$. And this $\tau$ is of the form thus it is in $A_n$
Q.E.D.

4-

- For $n=3 \Rightarrow A_3= \left \{ (123);(132) \right \} $ thus it is obvious that there isn't even enough elements in $A_3$ in order to be able to writte $ \sigma' = \tau \sigma \tau^{-1} $ with $ \sigma , \tau , \sigma' \in A_3 $ (all of them differentes permutations).
- For $n=4$ we have that the only permutation that sent $(123)$ to $(2;1;3)$ is $(1;2) \notin A_4 $

**I have a doubt concerning my conclusion in "-3" is it correct? Mostly because I don't see where we use the fact that $n \geq 5$ in my answer (so it seems to be correct for all $n$) But this is not the case.**

Thank for your help.

Comment: Why do you need $n\ge 5$? For this, it is enough to look for the proof for $A_5$, say, in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597451/conjugation-of-3-cycles-in-a-5). Can you see why we need $n=5$ there (and $n<5$ would fail)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde this is the question of my exercice I did not writte it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde My question IS NOT a duplicate of the one you ve linked.

Comment: It is exactly about the question, why you need at least $n=5$, although it is not an exact duplicate. But it answers your main question, namely what goes wrong for $n<5$. Check your proof for it (by comparison). You should set $n=5$ in your proof, to see it better. And of course, why don't you take the proof from the duplicate. It works in general.

Comment: Thk for your time. I know what goes wrong with $n<5$ see my part "4-" where I explain it tottaly. But i ve still a question on my part "3-" as because nowhere I uses the fact that $n \geq 5$ and that disturb me because in this case my demonstration seems to be correct for all $n$ and this is not the case.

Comment: Right, you made exactly this mistake, which you can find in the duplicate, why it is not possible. So your proof has a mistake - find it! The duplicate has the solution, why it fails.

Comment: euuuuh...I am a little bit confused by your answers. This is exactly because I did not succeed to find the mistake that I ve came to MS to ask this question :- )

Comment: I see. Well, in 2. you already find $a,b,c,d,e$ in $\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$. If $n<5$, then by the pigeon hole principle some of the letters are equal. Then one has to see whether this is possible.

Comment: Thk for your answer I think I ve understood what you re trying to explain to me. I am writting an answer to formalize it I hope that it will be true.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. On the other hand, we already have correct and beautiful proofs here. Why should you rewrite this? Others have done this often enough.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Because from what I understand the tip ou gave me is not complete and there is at least one other important fact that must be precise before using the pigeon hole principle. I ve written an answer, I will be happy to have your review on it.   

Thk a lot for your time.

Comment: Btw why my question has been dow voted???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below an explanation on why my prove is only correct for $n \geq 5$ .

i-
In my prove above in part "-3" I say that a permutation $\tau$ that solves this question has to verify $(\tau(a)=d; \tau(b)=e; \tau(c)=f )$ and the other elements of $S_n$ are unchanged but basically in $S_n$ there is $(n-3)!$ permutation that satisfy this condition, but by the question the permutation HAS to be too in $A_n$ that means that the correct permutation has to have an even number of permutation.

ii-
If $\tau \in A_n $ all ready so we have finished.
But if $\tau \notin A_n$ this means that $\tau$ contains an odd number of permutation. We can build an other valid permutation $\tau'$ this way $\tau' = (i;j) \circ \tau $ with $i,j \in S_n - \left \{  d;e;f \right \} $. Hence has we ve had an other permutation to $\tau$ the number of permuation is now even $ \Rightarrow \tau' \in A_n$. Moreover as $\tau'$ does not affect the 3-cycle permutation this does not modify the rest of our prove.

iii-
Now note that in the case of $n=3,4$ there is a unique permutation in $S_n$  satisfying the condition in "3-" in my question above (indeed $(4-3)!=1=(3-3)!$).
And obviously in order for $ \sigma $ to be in $A_n$ in the case of $n=3$ or $n=4$ we have that this unique permutation has to be a 3-cycle because in the other case we can not "correct" this unique permutation as we ve explained in "ii-" by the [pigeon hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20pigeonhole%20principle,contain%20more%20than%20one%20item.) .
*Exemple:* As we explained  only the permutatio $(12)$ verifies $(213)=(123)(12)(123)^{-1}$. Now obviouslt $(12) \notin A_n$ but we cannot correct $(12)$ by linking it with an other permutation $(i;j)$ because those $i,j$ should have to verify $i,j \neq 1,2,3 $ but still $i,j \in \left \{ 1,2,3,4 \right \} $ and this is not possible.