# Let $G$ be a normal non-trivial subgroup of $A_5$. Prove that $G=A_5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups

**I have a doubt concerning my part "4-".** And I iwould like to have your feedback on it. So you can jump directly there to read it (and read the other part if you feel that some justification are missing).

#### Question:

Let $G$ be a normal non-trivial sub group of $A_5$. Prove that $G=A_5$.

#### My answer:

1-
First let remind the definition of a normal sub group. A sub group $H$ of a group $G$ is said to be normal to $G$ if $\forall g \in G \Rightarrow gHg^{-1} \in H $. In more simple words it means that a normal sub group is "stable" under the action of conjugaison by any element of $G$ .

2-
By definition $A_5$ contains all the permutation that can be expressed by an even number of transposition (or equivalently that contains only an even number of transposition).
Thus $A_5$ only contains permutation of this form: 5-cycles $(a;b;c;d;e)$, 3-cycles $(a;b;c)$, product of two dysjoint 2-cyles $(a;b)(c;d)$ or a 0-cycle that means the identity permutation.
More over let remind to that the product of two disjoints 2-cycles can be written as the product of two 3-cycles. Indeed $(a;b)(c;d)=(a;c)(c;b)(c;b)(c;d)=(a;b;c)(b;c;d)$.
And because all 5-cycles can be expressed as composed of 2-cycles ( $(a;b;c;d;e)=((a;b)(b;c)(c;d)(d;e)$) it can be expressed too as composed of 3-cycles.

3-
We have all ready proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839236/n-geq-5-prove-that-the-3-cycles-of-a-n-are-pairwise-conjugates-in-a-n/4839251#4839251) that all the 3-cycles of $A_n$ are pairwise conjuguate in $A_n$ thus from "2-" we can easilly generalize and writte that all the elements of $A_5$ are pairwise conjuguate.
*!!!EDIT this is wrong but not important for the rest of the prove. thk to the comment of [Derek Holt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2820/derek-holt)!!! More generally in $A_5$ all elements of the same order are conjugate to each other.  *

4-
Let's assume that $G$ is a non trivial normal subgroup so it must contains at least one element $g' \in G$ that is not the permutation $Id$.
(i) In this case by the defintion of a normal sub group $\forall \sigma \in A_n \Rightarrow \sigma g' \sigma^{-1} \in G$
(ii) But on the other hand $\forall \sigma , \sigma' \in A_n , \exists \tau \in A_n $ s.t. $ \sigma' = \tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$.
And if we now take $\sigma= g' \Rightarrow $ then by (i) we have that $ \forall \tau \in A_n \Rightarrow  \tau g' \tau^{-1} \in G$ and by (ii) the formula $\tau g' \tau^{-1}$ describe $A_n$ entirely whan we make run $\tau $ over all the possible permutation of $A_n$.
Q.E.D.

**I have a doubt concerning my part "4-".** And I iwould like to have your feed back on it.  Indeed i am not sure if i did not "entangle" myself in the reasonning.
EDIT: More over I ve just noted that I ve made a mistake in the part "4-" while does not using the "3-cycles" property that I ve explained before. I am going to try to correct it.
Thank you.

Comment: This might not be relevant to the proof, but your statement at the end of 3 that all elements of the same order in $A_5$ are conjugate in $A_5$ is wrong for elements of order $5$. The elements $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $(1,2,3,5,4)$ are not conjugate in $A_5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank a lot. I ve red this on the net. I am goinf to edit my message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing my proof clearly has helped me to see where I was wrong so let's rewrite "4-".

a-
Let's assume that $G$ is a non trivial normal subgroup so it must contains at least one element $g′ ∈ G$ that is not the identity.
If $g'$ is 3-cyles so we are go to step "b-".
If $g'$ is of the form $\sigma = (ab)(cd); a \neq b \neq c \neq d$ then by definition of $G$ being a normal sub group we must have  $(bde) \sigma (bde)^{-1} =(bde) \sigma (edb) \in G $ and after that $(bde) \sigma (edb) \sigma^{-1} =(bdeca) \in G$ as the mutliplication of two elements $ (bde) \sigma (edb) $ and $ \sigma^{-1}$ in $G$. In other words $G$ contains too a 5-cycle.
Now following with the same logic we are going to prove that the fact that $G$ contains a 5-cycle (written "$\tau$" here) has for consequency that $G$ must contain too at least one 3-cycle. Formally with $ \tau=(abcde)$   we have that $(cde) \tau (cde)^{-1}=(cde) \tau (edc) \in G \Rightarrow (cde) \tau (edc) \tau^{-1}=(cda) \in G$ too as if $G$ is a subgroup so $\tau \in G \Rightarrow \tau^{-1} \in G$.
We writte this 3-cycle $ \in G$ as $g''$.

b-
On the other hand we proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839236/n-geq-5-prove-that-the-3-cycles-of-a-n-are-pairwise-conjugates-in-a-n/4839251#4839251) that  the 3-cycles of $A_5$ are pairwise conjuguates in $A_5$.
That means that in particular for $g'' \in G $ and for any fixed $\sigma' \in A_5 $ that is 3-cycle  we can write that  $\exists \tau \in A_5, \sigma' = \tau g'' \tau^{-1} $ and thus by definition of $G$ being a normal group $ \Rightarrow \sigma' \in G$ too.
In other words by using the definition of a normal subgroup all the 3-cycles can be obtained via $g''$.
But as we explained in "2-" all the 3-cycles describe entirely $A_5$.
Q.E.D.

Comment: `prove` is the verb, `proof` is the noun. "Writing my proof", not "my prove".

Comment: What you have written in a is wrong. If, for example, $g'$ is a $5$-cycle, then $g'$ is not conjugate to a $3$-cycle. Conjugate elements in permutation groups must have the same cycle-type.

Comment: Thk for your comment.I didn't say that. I said that a 5 cycle cna be written as a "multiplication" of 3-cycles

Comment: No you didn't, you said "we can find a 3-cycle by conjugation of $g'$ with other elements of $A_5'$".

Comment: Even though you have rewritten, you have not fixed your main bug. 
There is at least one 3-cycle in $G$, that's what you have to prove. 
This you have not done.
**Hint.** 
Consider three cases: $(1,2)(3,4)\in G$, $(1,2,3)\in G$, $(1,2,3,4,5)\in G$. So far you have investigated only the second case.

Comment: @kabenyuk thk a lot for your feedback  I ve edited my answer. Is it now correct?

Comment: @DerekHolt thk a lot for your feedback  I ve edited my answer. Is it now correct?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thk I ve corrected it.

Comment: Hello so does my edit as made my answer correct now ? @kabenyuk

Comment: So is my answer correct now?

Comment: @OffHakhol, Point (a) of your answer seems to be more or less properly now. But I don't like your notations at all. They're terrible:
why $g'$? why $abcde$? and so on.

Comment: @kabenyuk Thk for your review feel tottaly free to edit my message! As  I am just a under graduate student and this is my first course in  group theory my notation can be far from perfect and this is my first course where